# how to append a list of tag for a given object

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have the following use case

HTML input:

```
<div class='controls'>
</div>
```

---

My javascript code which does not work

```
var errors = ['error1', 'error2'];
inputElement.closest('.controls')
    .append($('<span/>').text(errors).addClass('error-message'));
```

---

The output should be:

```
<div class='controls'>
     <span class='error-message'>error1</span>
     <span class='error-message'>error</span>
</div>
```

---

Any ideas how to accomplish this task?
P.S.: I can use underscore and jquery

Comment: `$('.controls').closest('.controls')` makes no sense. Are you trying to select `.controls`??

Comment: it refers to `$('.controls')` I updated the question

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
var errors = ['errors1', 'errors2'];

$.each(errors, function() {
    $("<span>", { text : this, class : "error-message" }).appendTo("div.controls);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_.each(errors, function(e){
  inputElement.closest('.controls')
    .append($('<span>').text(e).addClass('error-message'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.controls')
  .append( $('<span>').addClass('error-message').text(errors[0]) )
  .append( $('<span>').addClass('error-message').text(errors[1]) );
```